# Some confusions about the logs in heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku

I have a laravel 8 project hosted in heroku.
I am trying to do logs like my dev environment.

In my dev environment, I have this *.env* file (extract) :

```
LOG_CHANNEL=daily
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

And this configuration in my *logging.php* file (extract) :

```
'channels' => [
        
        .....

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'days' => 14,
        ],

....
```

With that I have a single file per day, and the logs are keept automatically 14 days. It is very useful.

[image]

I want to reproduce the same thing in heroku hosting.

How to do that ? Is it a good practice ? How are you doing on your side ?

Comment: yeah it is a good pratices...

Comment: so after deployement laravel stops generating logs for 14 days. Am i right

Answer (score 0):

What is the confusion with Heroku? It will work the same there. If you have a new app of course you want to check the logs. I monitor them on all applications even if they are stable.

The logs are kept for 14 days then deleted. New ones will be generated.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging

One thing which is hard to figure out, is how to get the logs from Laravel in Heroku.

The answer is you need to ssh in to the Heroku instance, but...you are not really going in to the "box" you are instead going to a session copy so to speak.

So if you are ok with working in terminal, install Heroku Cli https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli
and then write

```
SSH: heroku ps:exec --app appname
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-ps-exec

You can also get the file directly by writing:

```
heroku ps:copy --app appname storage/logs/laravel.log -o /Users/Yourname/Downloads/laravel.log
```

and it will download the log. Ofc check the paths and the filenames as they can contain dates etc.

The .env is in Settings > Config Vars > Reveal Config Vars but you probably got that already?

Hope it works!